# Wordpress category posts filter by tag

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site where I want to make a page where posts are listed from a specific category. In this page there should be a tag filter that filtering the posts by tags from this category. Like portfolio images filtered by attributions. I need help to write a filter's code. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to custom program this. You can't do this with only the Divi builder.

Comment: Just visit the category archive page and add the get-param: post_tag=slug-of-tag should work out of the box. eg: `someplace.tld/?cat=vegetables&post_tag=nightshade` or `/category/vegetables?post_tag=leafy-greens`, whatever your url-schema is

Comment: Hey Norbert, Just to be sure I understand your question, Do you want to display posts from a specific category? Multiple categories? Try to be precise. On your theme does "portfolio images" is a custom post type? without detailed information, we can't do anything. Coders not wizards.

Answer (score 0):

@amarinediary I've already made a custom page template where posts listed from a "shops" category:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'category' => 101,
    'post_type' =>  'post',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'posts_per_page' => '-1000',
);

$postslist = get_posts( $args );?>  

<div class="entry-content shops">
                        
    <?php foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                        
        <div class="col-4">
                                  
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

                <div class="shop-info">

                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                    <span class="go">go to the shop <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>

                </div>
                                    
<?php the_post_thumbnail('name of your thumbnail'); ?>

              </a>

        </div>
                              
    <?php  endforeach;?>
    
</div> <!-- .entry-content -->
```

I'd like categorize these posts by tags, for example "bakery, bank, coffeeshop, fashion, etc.". I want place a filter in the top of the page, the filter has to contain only those tags that already ordered the posts from the "shops" category.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$query= new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'         => array('Your-Post-Type'),
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'orderby'           => 'DESC',
            'category' => 101,
            'tax_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     =>  array(
                        'slug1',
                        'slug2',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            ));
```